# Is the ratio $L_B / L_{H\alpha}$ important to determine star formation rates?

Tags: star-formation, definition

Could someone please tell me if the ratio $$\frac{L_B}{L_{H\alpha}}$$

is important in determining star formation rates?

Additionally, could someone please explain the implication of the ratio to me or direct me to a source?

Comment: You should give more details like what are the terms in this ratio to make your question clearer.

Comment: Is $L_B$ the $B$ band luminosity? If so, the ratio is a color. That doesn't really constrain the SFR (although larger SFRs generally lead to bluer colors). But your denominator can be used alone, through the [Kennicutt (1998)](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1998ARA%26A..36..189K) relation: $\mathrm{SFR} = 7.9\times10^{-42} L_{\mathrm{H}\alpha}$.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $L$ stands for [lumniosity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminosity), i.e. energy emitted per time interval, and the index is refering to the respective band:

- $L_{H \alpha}$ is the lumniosity of the visible spectral line in the Balmer series with $656.28 {\rm nm}$ wavelength
- $L_B$ might be the lumniosity for [B band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_band_(NATO)), i.e. for radio frequencies between $250\ldots 500 {\rm MHz}$, or for blue light of wavelength $445 {\rm nm}$ with [FWHM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_width_at_half_maximum) of $94 {\rm nm}$, as defined by the [photometric system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photometric_system) - which is the more proable assumption.

There are some [star-formation-rate indicators based on lumniosity](https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/Sept12/Calzetti/Calzetti1_2.html), but those seem to be based on a single band:

> [...] with constant star formation of 100 Myr, the non-ionising UV $(0.0912 \mu{\rm m} < \lambda < 0.3 \mu {\rm m})$ stellar continium can be converted to a SFR:
>
> $$ SFR(UV) = 3.0 \cdot 10^{-47} \lambda \, L(\lambda)$$
> with SFR(UV) in $M_\odot {\rm yr}^{-1}$, $\lambda$ in $\overset{\circ}{A}$, and $L(\lambda)$ in erg/s.

As @pela already mentioned in 2017, there is some relationship between star formation rate (SFR) and lumniosity of the ${\rm H \alpha}$ line alone, here cited from [Daniela Calzetti's web paper](https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/Sept12/Calzetti/Calzetti1_2.html), which essentially is [arXiv:1208.2997](https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.2997)

[image: Snapshot of above mentioned website]